# Windows batch file to iterate over extracted strings from a text file

Tags: string, windows, loops, batch-file

Given a text file file.txt containing

```
XXX-YYY-ZZZZ some other text
AAA-BBB-CCCC more text
UUU-VVV-WWWW etc etc
```

and a Windows .bat file

I'm seeking for a solution such that the string from each beginning of the line up to the first blank (excluding) will be extracted from the file and be given an executable in the .bat file as an argument.

The UNIX sh/sed pendant to which the following would be:

```
 for i in `cat file.txt | sed 's/ .*$//' `; do echo $i; done
```

with "echo" standing as a placeholder for the executable I would like to pass the argument to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1 delims= " %%a in ("file_path.txt") do echo %%a
```

?

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for.